# Drawing custom view android

Tags: java, android, xml, draw

i want to be professional on drawing custom view's in android , But I did not find a place to teach me or a full course that cover this topic .. can you help me with any course that start from scratch and make me professional on drawing on android ? :)

Answer (score 0):

make custom view is easy you need to do once :

1-create your coustom_view.xml(there l_rating_bar.xml).

2-create your Custom_view.java(there LRatingBar.java)
  and make your function and property field in this

3-use your custom view every where(MainActivity.java & activity_main.xml) and enjoy it

l_rating_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"             android:layoutDirection="ltr"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/star_1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_star_empty"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/star_2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_star_empty"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/star_3"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_star_empty"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/star_4"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_star_empty"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/star_5"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_star_empty"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LRatingBar.java:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.StyleableRes;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.moro.test.R;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)//For backward-compability
public class LRatingBar extends LinearLayout {
  @StyleableRes
  int index0 = 0;
  View rootView;
  ViewGroup ratingbar;
  public onChangeRateListener onChangeRateListener;
  ImageView star_1, star_2, star_3, star_4, star_5;
  public int rate = 0;

 public interface onChangeRateListener{
    void onchangeRate(int rate);
  }

  public LRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  public void onChangeRate(onChangeRateListener value){
    this.onChangeRateListener=value;
  }
  private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.l_rating_bar, this);

    int[] sets = {R.attr.rate};
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, sets);
    int rate = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.LRatingBar_rate,index0);
    typedArray.recycle();

    initComponents();
    setRate(rate);
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    ratingbar= findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
    star_1= findViewById(R.id.star_1);
    star_2= findViewById(R.id.star_2);
    star_3= findViewById(R.id.star_3);
    star_4= findViewById(R.id.star_4);
    star_5= findViewById(R.id.star_5);


  }

  public void clickable(boolean i){
    if (i){
     star_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         emptyAllStar();
        setRate(1);
        onChangeRateListener.onchangeRate(getRate());
       }
     });
     star_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         emptyAllStar();
        setRate(2);
         onChangeRateListener.onchangeRate(getRate());
       }
     });
     star_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         emptyAllStar();
        setRate(3);
         onChangeRateListener.onchangeRate(getRate());
       }
     });
     star_4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         emptyAllStar();
        setRate(4);
         onChangeRateListener.onchangeRate(getRate());
       }
     });
     star_5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         emptyAllStar();
        setRate(5);
         onChangeRateListener.onchangeRate(getRate());
       }
     });

    }else {

    }
  }



  public int getRate() {
    return rate;
  }

  public void setRate(int value) {
    rate=value;
    switch (rate){
      case 1:
        star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        break;
      case 2:
        star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        break;
      case 3:
        star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        break;
      case 4:
        star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        break;
      case 5:
        star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        star_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_filled);
        break;
    }
 }

  private void emptyAllStar(){
    star_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_empty);
    star_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_empty);
    star_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_empty);
    star_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_empty);
    star_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ui_star_empty);
  }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
   <your.package.name.LRatingBar
                  android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
LRatingBar  ratingBar = (LRatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    ratingBar .setRate(value_item_section_review.rate);
    ratingBar .clickable(true);
    ratingBar .onChangeRate(new LRatingBar.onChangeRateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onchangeRate(int rate) {
      }
    });
```

Comment: my problem not on making a custom view ! i want a full course to learn drawing on android .. i want to learn and be professional and understand all this staff.

Comment: the best way to learn drawing on android and etc. is https://developer.android.com/ - i suggest it because it's  best reference and easy for use